# How to group longitude and latitude reducing the decimal places of those points?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregate:

```
db.locations.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-47.121314, -18.151515 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 500,
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 50000,
        spherical: true
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $group: {
         "_id" : {
            'loc' : '$loc'
         },
         qtd: { $sum:1 } 
        }
    },
], );
```

And the following collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId(), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -47.121311, 
            -18.151512
        ]
    }
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId(), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -47.121311, 
            -18.151512
        ]
    }
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId(), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -47.121312, 
            -18.151523
        ]
    }
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId(), 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -47.121322, 
            -18.151533
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run the aggregate, I have the following result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [
                -47.121311, 
                -18.151512
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "qtd" : 2.0
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [
                -47.121312, 
                -18.151523
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "qtd" : 1.0
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [
                -47.121322, 
                -18.151533
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "qtd" : 1.0
}
```

I would like to group these locations in a single document, since they are very close ..

I thought of reducing the size of each point, `-47.121314` being something like `-47.1213`

Something like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [
                -47.1213, 
                -18.1515
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "qtd" : 4.0
}
```

But I have no idea how to group these documents.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to reduce the floating point precision is to [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) out the number by the required precision adjustment, "truncate it" to an integer and then [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) back to the desired precision.

For latest MongoDB releases ( since MongoDB 3.2 ) you can use [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/):

```
db.locations.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": { 
      "type": "Point", 
      "coordinates": [ -47.121314, -18.151515 ]
    },
    "distanceField": "qtd",
    "maxDistance": 500,
    "num": 50000,
    "spherical": true
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": '$loc.type',
      "coordinates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": '$loc.coordinates',
          "in": {
            "$divide": [
              { "$trunc": { "$multiply": [ '$$this', 10000 ] } },
              10000
            ]                
          }
        }    
      }
    },
    "qtd": { "$sum": '$qtd' }    
  }}
]);
```

For releases prior to that, you can use [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) and [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to remove the "remainder" instead:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": { 
      "type": "Point", 
      "coordinates": [ -47.121314, -18.151515 ]
    },
    "distanceField": "qtd",
    "maxDistance": 500,
    "num": 50000,
    "spherical": true
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": '$loc.type',
      "coordinates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": '$loc.coordinates',
          "as": "coord",
          "in": {
            "$divide": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$multiply": [ '$$coord', 10000 ] },
                { "$mod": [
                  { "$multiply": [ '$$coord', 10000 ] },
                  1
                ]}
              ]},
              10000
            ]                
          }
        }    
      }
    },
    "qtd": { "$sum": '$qtd' }    
  }}
]);
```

Both return the same result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -47.1213, 
            -18.1515
        ]
    },
    "qtd" : 4.01180839007879
}
```

We use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) here to "reshape" the array contents of `"coordinates"` applying the "rounding" to each value in the array. You might note the two slightly different usages with `"as'` in the second example, since the ability to use `$$this` as a default reference was only applied in MongoDB 3.2, for which the listing presumes you would not have or otherwise you would use [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) instead of the alternate method usage.

You should note that [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) which is essentially a "nearest" search is only returning `100` documents by default or alternately up to the number specified in `"num"` or `"limit"` options. So that is always a governing factor in the number of results returned if those would exceed the other constraints such as `"maxDistance"`.

There is also no need to follow the documentation so literally, as `"distanceField"` is the only other mandatory parameter aside from `"spherical"` which is required when a `"2dsphere"` index is used. The value to `"distanceField"` can be whatever you actually want it to be, and in this case we simply supply it directly with the name of the property you want to output.